# Cannot Link Existing Project to Google Play Console API

Tags: api, console, playback

When I click on link existing project under API access on the Google Play Console, my existing cloud project does not show up.

Answer (score 22):

Since I am the owner of my Google Play Console account, the only thing that was missing for me - to enable the Google Play Developer API for the existing project:

**1) Type the "Google Play Developer API"** in the search box on the project's home screen.

**2) Then Click** on the "Google Play Android Developer API" search result:

[image]

**3) Click "Enable"**

[image]

**4) (!!!) Refresh the Google Play Console page with API settings**

Answer (score 12):

From Google Play Developer API docs

Using an existing project
If you are already a user of the Google Play Developer API, you can link to your existing API project by following these steps:

Go to the API access page on the Google Play Console.
Accept the API Terms of Service.
Choose the project you’d like to link.

If your project isn’t listed, verify that

1. your Google Play Console account is designated as an Owner
2. Google Play Developer API is enabled for the project